# Setting Up Development Environment for Blender Project

Tags: python, eclipse, blender

I am trying to setup the development environment to run the source code of the Blender project. I have downloaded the source code from [here](http://mirror.cs.umn.edu/blender.org/source/blender-2.73a.tar.gz)

I have installed Eclipse on my OS(Win-7) and set up environment for Python using PyDev. Now I need to ask how can I be able to load the Blender project. I mean to say which files should be loaded as I dont have any idea by how the flow goes in this project . I have imported the 'blender-2.73a\source' folder in to my project on Eclipse. I need some guidance on this , as how this flow is working or point me my mistake if  I am doing anything wrong here. Thanks n Regards

Answer (score 0):

The blender project uses [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) to generate Makefiles. The main cmake file is called CMakeLists.txt and can be found at the top of the source tree (there are also others in every sub-directory). cmake can also generate an [eclipse project](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/Eclipse_CDT4_Generator).

Rather than working with the release source tarball you should use git to checkout the repo using instructions at [developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/). Once you have a copy of the repo you can create your own branch and commit your changes, then easily create a diff of modifications against the master branch.

You probably want to look over the [building blender steps](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Windows/msvc/CMake) to ensure you have everything you need installed. There are pre-build windows binaries for most dependencies, I think you need to have msvc installed to compile on windows.

Comment: I am trying to generate the solution file through CMake ,. I am currently using the source I downloaded from blender. But CMake is throwing an error that "Error in configuration, Project files may be invalid" . What does that suppose to mean? Am I giving the wrong source path

Comment: Could be a few cause, would need to see the output above the error to have a better idea. Would be worth asking another question with the cmake command and it's output.

Comment: I have build the Blender.sln file and now When I am loading it ion VS, it gives me error. The problem here is not the errors , the main thing I am lacking is the flow of how the things work while compiling Blender project. Like first , we have to build the source code through Cmake, then we will compile through VS . Then we will call the scripts .Is that so ? I really need guidance on this

Comment: The source files are what you extract from the source download. cmake uses some config files in there to generate the makefiles used to compile blender, then (on *nix systems) make is used to compile the binary to run. In your case instead of generating the makefiles, cmake is creating a project file that you open in an IDE and compile instead of using make.

Comment: Ok may be Im getting you . You mean to say in my case I will be using the exe file made by the ide .Then where is the use of Python . I am little confused for that.

Comment: The result of cmake/eclipse is to compile blender. You can use eclipse to alter the blender source code to add features or fix bugs. blender includes a python interpreter that allows you to use python scripts to automate or add features to blender without adjusting the source code - not everything can be achieved in python. blenders text editing is fairly simple so you may want to use an external editor to edit the python scripts you run.

Comment: If I have to do some changes in blender , I would have to do in source code before coming to CMake. ok ! And that changes will be done through Python Console. But u said "without adjusting the source code". Whats that mean. I am new to blender thats why I m a little more concerned.

Comment: If you look through the addons you will find that the python addon scripts add various features to blender using python. Some things can't be achieved or would be slow using python and would need to be implemented in the source code. After altering the source you will need to rebuild blender with cmake.

Comment: Whenever I make changes to source , I have to rebuild with CMake and generate the exe through VS. OK. But currently I am facing too many synatx errors when building with VS. Have you any idea of that? Because its the first time I am generating the exe. Idont know why there are so many errors

Comment: You probably want to chat with someone [on IRC](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Community:Chat) in blendercoders or blendercompilers for more detailed help.